# VB - Get TableRow By ID

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have been trying to check if a TableRow ID exists, and if so, add a cell to it.

Initially I start with:

```
If Request.Form(sID) IsNot Nothing Then
        AddCel(sID)
End If
```

Then, before adding the cell, I attempt to add the cell from the VB side:

```
tblTable.Rows.GetRowIndex(sID)
```

But I think I've gotten table ID confused with table index, and the two don't work the same way. Unfortunately, I'm not sure if there's an equivalent for searching for an ID. My goal was to then add the control to the table row after getting the row based on the ID, but I'm at a standstill. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Blackcat that shouldn't be any different than the `If` that's being used.  I'd typically recommend to use the form in the question.

Comment: @Blackcat Sure, but that's VBA.  It's a well-established form in .NET VB.

Comment: Is this asp.net and a web site? I would do this test against the datasource (the data table) and add the column BEFORE you bind to say the asp.net GridView, or ListView, or whatever web control you are using to display that table of data.